# Will there be potential problems if changing Xamarin.Android project's IDE from VS 2017 Community Edition to VS 2019 Community Edition?

Tags: xamarin.android, ide, project, swap

From november 2019 to may 2020 I've been creating `Xamarin.Android` project on `Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition`. Back then I decided its IDE to be `Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition` instead of `Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition` because my PC didn't have the system requirements for `VS 2019 Community Edition`. Now I will work on another PC that will have the requirements for `VS 2019 Community Edition`.  As I've read that `VS 2019 Community Edition`  reduces developing time compared to `VS 2017 Community Edition`  I'm planning to continue the development of the same `Xamarin.Android` project on `VS 2019 Community Edition`. My question is if I change the project's IDE, will I have some issues in the present and in the near and far future related to the change of IDE? Because if I reduce developing time with `VS 2019 Community Edition` but then I lose that time and even more time in fixing issues related to the change of IDE, it's not worth it to change the IDE.

Furthermore I have the fear of an irreparable error related to the change of IDE happening at the very end of the project's development, in this case I could change the project's IDE to `VS 2017 Community Edition` again but what if I start getting errors in that IDE too for having developed in `VS 2019 Community Edition` for some time and that way I won't be able to continue working on the project. Is it possible that scenario also to happen and all my efforts to create the project to be in vain and the client to be left without the app he needs in time?

Can I be 100% sure that there won't be any problem related to the change of IDE to `VS 2019 Community Edition` during all the developing period?

Comment: For Visual studio 2019,compared 2017, only some feature s have been added. If you create and develop project on visual studio 2017, then use visual studio 2019 to continue, it is ok, having no problem.

Comment: And if after, for example, 3 or 4 months of development in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, I decide to change again the project's IDE to Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, will I get errors for having developed in VS 2019 Community Edition for some time?

Comment: I think  it is no problem.